# Why PHP and Ajax does not return responses?

Tags: php, html, ajax

file upload works with ajax and php, but does not return responses! in the upload.php page is displayed:

uploaded succesfully!

html:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
        <div style="padding: 15px;">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        </div>
        <div style="padding: 15px">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="upload">
        </div>
</form>
```

ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,

                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            })
        })
})
```

php:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {    
    $file_destination = "uploads/IMG-" . date("Y-m-d") . time() . ".jpg";

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file_destination)) {
        echo "uploaded succesfully!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about `e.preventDefault()` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: Or [jQuery AJAX file upload PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue exist on client side use this html and java script code hope your issue will be resolved

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
<div style="padding: 15px;">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
</div>
<div style="padding: 15px">
    <button value="Upload" id="upload">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

js part

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#upload').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        // cache: false,
        processData: false,

        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}); });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it works! thank you engineer